# How to create a dynamic JSON array based on parse.com database

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I'm looking for a way to create a JSON dynamic array that looks like this: `{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "National Geographic Channel",
            "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/cosmos.jpg",
            "status": "\"Science is a beautiful and emotional human endeavor,\" says Brannon Braga, executive producer and director. \"And Cosmos is all about making science an experience.\"",
            "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/nat.jpg",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": null
        },`

This needs to be generated in the cloud of Parse.com, and has to be based on Parse database then it needs to return a JSON array link that contains JSON arrays so I could be able later to use it on my Android application

If this method is not the best one to work with, could you please provide a better one.

I'm still a newbie in App developpement. Any help would be really appriciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Have you tried using Parse's API to query for that document? And as long as you have valid JSON, you can do anything with in it Android, though I would recommend the Parse SDK directly instead of JSON parsing.

Answer (score 0):

https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_toJSON

I think your use of the term "dynamic" is confusing... nevertheless I think I understand.  From what I can gather you're using Parse.com JavaScript Core SDK, you've created a Class, you want to pull from the object and convert it to JSON format (if so, see my example below).

***or use my method...***

```
Parse.initialize("appId", "javascriptKey", "masterKey");
var Blog = Parse.Object.extend("Blog");
var Query = new Parse.Query(Blog);

Query.find({
    success: function(parseData) {
        var dataString = JSON.stringify(parseData);
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(dataString);

        // now use jsonData
        console.log(dataString);
        console.log(jsonData);
    },
    error: function(parseData, error) {
        console.log("Unable to query the Parse object");
    }
});
```